# Como pasar un JSON a un Objeto?

Tags: json, angularjs-2.0, typescript

Buen Día

Mi Problemas es tengo este JSON

```
{"status":"success","code":200,"data":[{"ID":70}]}
```

Que lo obtuve de esta funcion para que sea mas claro:

```
this._service.getDato().subscribe(
        result =>   this.datosParaEditar(result.data)
        )
```

Al obtener result.data quiero guardarlo en un objeto como esto

```
public data: IdModelo; // que es el objeto

datosParaEditar(result){
    this.data = new IdModelo(result.ID);
}
```

pero al imprimirlo me sale que result.ID es nulo y esta vació, y al imprimir por consola solo result, se imprime el JSON [{"ID":70}], quisiera saber como puedo guardar este dato en un Objeto.

Comment: ya probaste haciendo result[0].ID ?

Comment: Woooo!!. No lo probe asi, me podrias explicar porque se necesito agregar la posicion 0?. jajajaj Gracias @CamiloVasquez si sirvio

Comment: Sucede que el valor de result.data es un arreglo con 1 elemento, por ende tienes que acceder primero al indice 0 del arreglo para obtener el objeto, y luego recién puedes acceder a la propiedad ID de dicho objeto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te fijas bien `"data":[{"ID":70}]` guarda un `array de objetos` por lo cual para poder acceder al valor que quieres debes entrar primero a la posición 0 de ese `array` y ahí si podrás acceder a las propiedades de dicho objeto.

Comment: Claro claro, si te entiendo, el caso que traiga mas ID, son las demás posiciones. Muchas gracias @Camilo

Comment: El caso de que te traiga mas índices puedes hacer ya un for para recorrerlos e ir agregando uno por uno.

Answer (score 2):

Existen varias formas, en primera instancia podrías utilizar `JSON.parse()`   al suscribirte al `Observable` que retorna tu servicio, sin embargo eso no es lo mejor, ya que Angular provee una forma de parsear el JSON directamente cuando defines tu servicio si utilizas el módulo `HttpModule`, disponible en `@angular/http`. Sólo debes `map`ear la respuesta de tu servicio y ocupar el método `.json()`, por ejemplo:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http'
@Injectable()
export class fooService{
  constructor( private http: Http ) {}

  getDato() {
    return this.http.get('endpoint').map(res => res.json())
  }
}
```

Desde Angular `4.3` se introdujo un nuevo módulo HTTP llamado `HttpClientModule`, y se importa desde `@angular/common/http`, y con esta versión ya no es necesario `map`ear dicha respuesta, por lo tanto tu servicio se vería algo así:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
@Injectable()
export class fooService{
  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {}

  getDato() {
    return this.http.get('endpoint');
  }
}
```

En resumen:
Si usas el módulo http antiguo, debes usar `.map()` y retornar `res.json()`, si usas el módulo nuevo, la respuesta ya viene como objeto y no es necesario convertir el JSON.

Comment: Definitivamente me sirvió también esta respuesta. porque actualmente en mi proyecto estoy usando la Forma antigua. Muchas Gracias @Osman por tu apunte.

Comment: De nada, de hecho no leí bien la pregunta inicialmente, no me había fijado en lo del arreglo, por eso mi respuesta.

Comment: Si, pero aun así este aporte viene de Gran ayuda, seguiré implementando mas cosas de Angular Material D